# Make image above the fold

Tags: javascript, css, squarespace

for [this page](https://heba-asmar.squarespace.com), I'm having trouble with how the page displays on different sized monitors, even just on desktop.  How can I get the entire main image to display above the fold dynamically?  Thanks!

Comment: did you try setting the height of the html and body elements to a value greater than the height of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'vh' units. [Read more](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) about 'vh' units.
see [supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh)

---

Example (your page):

I added `height: 100vh;` to `<figure id="thumbnail" >...</figure>` and `height: 100%; width: 100%;` to the `<img>` inside it (removing all other style you had there) - it did the trick

Comment: Really helpful, thank you.  What if I want to make the entire page, including the header and footer, fit within the 100vh?

Comment: I tried this in the browser.  Adding height: 100vh worked but created a blue line under the image as I made the browser smaller.  I added height:100% to the img section for the img element but the browser keeps crossing it out, as if it's not a legitimate style.  It kept this styling even after I changed it: style="top: 0px; left: -172px; width: 1274px; position: relative; height: 730px;">